# Boostrap responsive column centered width "jumping"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**markup:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" style="height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 100px; background-color: blue;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When i'm lowering browser width col-md-12 is scaled down to fit width. For each screen width range col-md-12 width is less than range before.

But it's not the same with col-md-8 col-md-offset-2. First width is lowered but then increased. To illustrate the problem i have prepared screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezrop.png

I suspect that it's "by default", but maybe you have encountered this problem and got solution? I would like col-md-8 to act like col-md-12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`col-md-8 col-md-offset-2` means "When the width is medium or higher, make the div 8 out of 12 columns wide and push it two across so it is in the middle".

When you return the window width to small, then you no longer have any rules, so it goes to being the full width.

If you want to specify a width for when it it small, then do so. Use `sm` instead of `md`.

Comment: md scaling is ok for me, except this "jumping". sm is too small i mid range screen widths.

Comment: 100% of the widest size that counts as small is wider than 80% of the smallest size that counts as medium. There is nothing you can do to change that. It is just how maths works.

Comment: I accept maths rules :) i'm just looking for a hack for this behavior.